# Bootstrap modal not rendering iframe

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, spotify

Can't quite figure out what is causing the breakdown here. But I'm pulling directly from the modal example on the Bootstrap website. Attempting to embed Spotify iFrame unsuccessfully. Any pointers on how to get the content to render? aka desired outcome would be ability to play spotify playlist.

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
      <iframe src="https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:1270558680:playlist:6nfXkdY7eZwINySrDHIFiV" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>  </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
     <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the 'modal-dialog' div, the 'modal-content' div, and a few closing divs.

I copied the modal example straight from the bootstrap website, inserted your iframe, and it worked ([Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/aKfvs/1/)). Here's the example modal from bootstrap's website:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The iFrame is not display at the correct place when you load the page that's why when you click on load the modal doesn't display the good part of the iFrame.

Have you tried that : http://www.bootply.com/61676

Answer (score -1):

You can use [eModal,js](http://saribe.github.io/eModal)! *(5kb only)*

The simply way:

```
eModal.iframe("https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:0YtFqZhheQZIrVc0qbqL8D")
```

Some makeup:

```
eModal.iframe({
    url: "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:track:0YtFqZhheQZIrVc0qbqL8D",
    size:eModal.size.sm,
    title:"Da weasel"});
```

This lib also supports ajax, alert, promp or confirm.

**No html required!**